# bus error apt-get upgrade libc-bin

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, 16.10

I am on Ubuntu 16.10 in a VMware Environment as guest.
Since several weeks my system crashes when I try to upgrade the packages.

It happens exactly when the package manager tries to configure libc-bin:

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen...
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut....
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen....
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet...
Die folgenden Pakete sind zurückgehalten worden:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  desktop-file-utils firefox firefox-locale-de firefox-locale-en
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gnome-calculator gtk-update-icon-cache imagemagick
  imagemagick-6.q16 imagemagick-common libegl1-mesa libgail-3-0 libgbm1 libgd3
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa
  libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libmagickcore-6.q16-2
  libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libnm-gtk-common
  libnm-gtk0 libnma-common libnma0 libnss-resolve libpam-systemd libsystemd0
  libtiff5 libudev1 libwayland-egl1-mesa libxatracker2 linux-libc-dev
  mesa-common-dev network-manager-gnome snap-confine snapd systemd
  systemd-sysv tcpdump ubuntu-core-launcher udev

Extrahiere Vorlagen aus Paketen: 65%
Extrahiere Vorlagen aus Paketen: 100%
46 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 3 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 74,3 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 927 kB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) wird eingerichtet ...

Bus error (core dumped)

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once

/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:

    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so

/usr/local/lib:

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:

    libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02.1

    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0

    libiw.so.30 -> libiw.so.30

    libatm.so.1 -> libatm.so.1.0.0

    libisc-export.so.160 -> libisc-export.so.160.0.0

    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1

    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so

    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.14.7

    libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0

    libx86.so.1 -> libx86.so.1

    libnss_mdns4.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4.so.2

    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.24.so

    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.24.so

    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.24.so

    libsmartcols.so.1 -> libsmartcols.so.1.1.0

    libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.22.0

    libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2

    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4

    libmnl.so.0 -> libmnl.so.0.2.0

    libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4

    libply.so.4 -> libply.so.4.0.0

    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8

    libpcsclite.so.1 -> libpcsclite.so.1.0.0

    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1

    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so

    libseccomp.so.2 -> libseccomp.so.2.3.1

    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9

    libatasmart.so.4 -> libatasmart.so.4.0.5

    libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0

    libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2

    libmvec.so.1 -> libmvec-2.24.so

    libnss_mdns.so.2 -> libnss_mdns.so.2

    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so

    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.24.so

    libbrlapi.so.0.6 -> libbrlapi.so.0.6.5

    libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.7

    libdns-export.so.162 -> libdns-export.so.162.1.3

    libcap-ng.so.0 -> libcap-ng.so.0.0.0

    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.2

    libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.7.0

    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.24.so

    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.24.so

    libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.25

    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.24.so

    libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.3

    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.24.so

    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.19.1

    libparted-fs-resize.so.0 -> libparted-fs-resize.so.0.0.1

    liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0

    libnss_mdns6.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6.so.2

    libssl.so.1.0.0 -> libssl.so.1.0.0

    libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.2

    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5

    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0

    libntfs-3g.so.871 -> libntfs-3g.so.871.0.0

    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1

    libply-splash-graphics.so.4 -> libply-splash-graphics.so.4.0.0

    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6

    libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2

    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.24.so

    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0

    libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9

    libnih-dbus.so.1 -> libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0

    libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.1.2

    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1

    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.24.so

    libnss_resolve.so.2 -> libnss_resolve.so.2

    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.24.so

    libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.3

    libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0

    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.24.so

    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.24.so

    libcgmanager.so.0 -> libcgmanager.so.0.0.0

    libprocps.so.6 -> libprocps.so.6.0.0

    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.24.so

    libapparmor.so.1 -> libapparmor.so.1.4.0

    liblzo2.so.2 -> liblzo2.so.2.0.0

    libaudit.so.1 -> libaudit.so.1.0.0

    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.24.so

    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.24.so

    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3

    libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.3.0

    libhistory.so.7 -> libhistory.so.7.0

    libpci.so.3 -> libpci.so.3.3.1

    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0

    libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.5

    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.24.so

    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so

    libjson-c.so.3 -> libjson-c.so.3.0.0

    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.1

    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0

    libreadline.so.7 -> libreadline.so.7.0

    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.24.so

    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9

    libply-splash-core.so.4 -> libply-splash-core.so.4.0.0

    libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.16.0

    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0

    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0

    libulockmgr.so.1 -> libulockmgr.so.1.0.1

    libnl-genl-3.so.200 -> libnl-genl-3.so.200.22.0

    libidn.so.11 -> libidn.so.11.6.16

    libnewt.so.0.52 -> libnewt.so.0.52.18

    libparted.so.2 -> libparted.so.2.0.1

    libply-boot-client.so.4 -> libply-boot-client.so.4.0.0

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring



    ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.24.so

    libmount.so.1 -> libmount.so.1.1.0

    libfdisk.so.1 -> libfdisk.so.1.1.0

    libsepol.so.1 -> libsepol.so.1

    libslang.so.2 -> libslang.so.2.3.0

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:

Bus error (core dumped)

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes libc-bin (--configure):

 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 135 zurück

Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:

 libc-bin

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to fix this via dpkg:

```
libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu2) wird eingerichtet ...
Bus error (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
    libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 -> libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
    libiw.so.30 -> libiw.so.30
    libatm.so.1 -> libatm.so.1.0.0
    libisc-export.so.160 -> libisc-export.so.160.0.0
    libpamc.so.0 -> libpamc.so.0.82.1
    libmemusage.so -> libmemusage.so
    libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.14.7
    libnih.so.1 -> libnih.so.1.0.0
    libx86.so.1 -> libx86.so.1
    libnss_mdns4.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4.so.2
    libutil.so.1 -> libutil-2.24.so
    libresolv.so.2 -> libresolv-2.24.so
    libdl.so.2 -> libdl-2.24.so
    libsmartcols.so.1 -> libsmartcols.so.1.1.0
    libnl-3.so.200 -> libnl-3.so.200.22.0
    libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
    libext2fs.so.2 -> libext2fs.so.2.4
    libmnl.so.0 -> libmnl.so.0.2.0
    libbz2.so.1.0 -> libbz2.so.1.0.4
    libply.so.4 -> libply.so.4.0.0
    libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8
    libpcsclite.so.1 -> libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
    libselinux.so.1 -> libselinux.so.1
    libSegFault.so -> libSegFault.so
    libseccomp.so.2 -> libseccomp.so.2.3.1
    libncursesw.so.5 -> libncursesw.so.5.9
    libatasmart.so.4 -> libatasmart.so.4.0.5
    libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
    libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6_minimal.so.2
    libmvec.so.1 -> libmvec-2.24.so
    libnss_mdns.so.2 -> libnss_mdns.so.2
    libthread_db.so.1 -> libthread_db-1.0.so
    librt.so.1 -> librt-2.24.so
    libbrlapi.so.0.6 -> libbrlapi.so.0.6.5
    libfuse.so.2 -> libfuse.so.2.9.7
    libdns-export.so.162 -> libdns-export.so.162.1.3
    libcap-ng.so.0 -> libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
    libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.2
    libcryptsetup.so.4 -> libcryptsetup.so.4.7.0
    libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.24.so
    libanl.so.1 -> libanl-2.24.so
    libcap.so.2 -> libcap.so.2.25
    libcrypt.so.1 -> libcrypt-2.24.so
    libpcre.so.3 -> libpcre.so.3.13.3
    libnsl.so.1 -> libnsl-2.24.so
    libgpg-error.so.0 -> libgpg-error.so.0.19.1
    libparted-fs-resize.so.0 -> libparted-fs-resize.so.0.0.1
    liblzma.so.5 -> liblzma.so.5.0.0
    libnss_mdns6.so.2 -> libnss_mdns6.so.2
    libssl.so.1.0.0 -> libssl.so.1.0.0
    libexpat.so.1 -> libexpat.so.1.6.2
    libkeyutils.so.1 -> libkeyutils.so.1.5
    libuuid.so.1 -> libuuid.so.1.3.0
    libntfs-3g.so.871 -> libntfs-3g.so.871.0.0
    libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
    libply-splash-graphics.so.4 -> libply-splash-graphics.so.4.0.0
    libwrap.so.0 -> libwrap.so.0.7.6
    libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2 -> libnss_mdns_minimal.so.2
    libc.so.6 -> libc-2.24.so
    libss.so.2 -> libss.so.2.0
    libtinfo.so.5 -> libtinfo.so.5.9
    libnih-dbus.so.1 -> libnih-dbus.so.1.0.0
    libgcrypt.so.20 -> libgcrypt.so.20.1.2
    libgcc_s.so.1 -> libgcc_s.so.1
    libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.24.so
    libnss_resolve.so.2 -> libnss_resolve.so.2
    libm.so.6 -> libm-2.24.so
    libbsd.so.0 -> libbsd.so.0.8.3
    libusb-1.0.so.0 -> libusb-1.0.so.0.1.0
    libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.24.so
    libpthread.so.0 -> libpthread-2.24.so
    libcgmanager.so.0 -> libcgmanager.so.0.0.0
    libprocps.so.6 -> libprocps.so.6.0.0
    libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.24.so
    libapparmor.so.1 -> libapparmor.so.1.4.0
    liblzo2.so.2 -> liblzo2.so.2.0.0
    libaudit.so.1 -> libaudit.so.1.0.0
    libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.24.so
    libcidn.so.1 -> libcidn-2.24.so
    libe2p.so.2 -> libe2p.so.2.3
    libkmod.so.2 -> libkmod.so.2.3.0
    libhistory.so.7 -> libhistory.so.7.0
    libpci.so.3 -> libpci.so.3.3.1
    libblkid.so.1 -> libblkid.so.1.1.0
    libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.5
    libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.24.so
    libpcprofile.so -> libpcprofile.so
    libjson-c.so.3 -> libjson-c.so.3.0.0
    libpam.so.0 -> libpam.so.0.83.1
    libpam_misc.so.0 -> libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
    libreadline.so.7 -> libreadline.so.7.0
    libBrokenLocale.so.1 -> libBrokenLocale-2.24.so
    libncurses.so.5 -> libncurses.so.5.9
    libply-splash-core.so.4 -> libply-splash-core.so.4.0.0
    libsystemd.so.0 -> libsystemd.so.0.16.0
    libattr.so.1 -> libattr.so.1.1.0
    libacl.so.1 -> libacl.so.1.1.0
    libulockmgr.so.1 -> libulockmgr.so.1.0.1
    libnl-genl-3.so.200 -> libnl-genl-3.so.200.22.0
    libidn.so.11 -> libidn.so.11.6.16
    libnewt.so.0.52 -> libnewt.so.0.52.18
    libparted.so.2 -> libparted.so.2.0.1
    libply-boot-client.so.4 -> libply-boot-client.so.4.0.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes libc-bin (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 135 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 libc-bin
```

Any suggestions are welcome, I can't upgrade, I can't delete libc-bin (system warns me that this is a dangerous operation).

Comment: Can you recall if you did anything out of the ordinary right before it started happening? Like upgrading the kernel or something?

Comment: This system is only used for my Android builds. So my normal workflow is boot it only every ~10 days, `apt-get upgrade`, then `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `repo sync`. The bus errors start to appear after a dist-upgrade when booting next time (I think it started begin of February).

Comment: Well, a `dist-upgrade` upgrades the kernel, so maybe switching to an older kernel will fix it? You can select an older kernel under the advanced menu in GRUB.

Comment: I tried with the older kernel. Keeps also crashing, when I want to update the packages (not the kernel).

Comment: It's getting interesting. The problem either lies within VMWare or within drivers for SSD or the SSD (Crucial MX-300) itself. Always, when the bus error occurs and my SSD is connected via SATA, the drive vanishes from the explorer and I have to re-plug it in. When using a USB3-SATA connector, it just crashes but doesn't disappear from the explorer. So I copied the whole virtual disk to my internal SATA drive and ran it from there. No bus errors anymore, apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade just went fine. So it has nothing to do with Ubuntu than the Windows environment or even hardware troubles.

Comment: Okay, I'm voting to close this as the problem went away on its own / not reproducible then.